# WebStorm doesn't work fine with Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, webstorm

Trying to work with Ionic framework with JetBrains WebStorm and met some troubles, which I couldn't resolve.

1. WebStorm doesn't use SCSS classes to suggest completion in HTML. Basically, Ionic's each page consists 3 files: HTML, SCSS and TypeScript, and all of these have same name. As [this](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2018/03/webstorm-2018-1-eap-181-4096/) link says, WebStorm do suggest project-wide. But it's not.

   Does anyone except met same trouble?
2. Ionic attributes doesn't paste correct from completions suggest. For example, if I'm trying to get completion for `ion-button` attribute it added as `ion-button=""` instead just `ion-button`, no matter how I add this completion - mouse click, enter hit or tab key hit. And I just can't find those templates to remove from them symbols `=""`.

   Any advices how to fix this?

Comment: 1. it does. try hitting `Ctrl+space` twice - does it help? And what webstorm version do you use, BTW? 2. you can try disabling *Add quotes for attribute value on typing '='* in *Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys*

Comment: 1. No, it don't for now. It suggests come classes, but there is no new classes, which I've added for a while. But I can see some old classes, which were added some time ago. Maybe it have to make new index for suggestions?
I'm using WebStorm 2018.1.3
2. But I just want to disable adding `=""` only for some attributes from Ionic, not for all. Or to add quotes after input `=`.

Comment: 1. try invalidating caches - does the completion work after it? 2. feel free to file a request for this feature to youtrack, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Comment: @lena 1. Nope, it doesn't help me. Webstorm doesn't suggest any class names from my .scss files. Nor standard completion, nor double ctrl+space. It suggests some classes from Ionic's, but no one from any .scss in whole project.
2. Ok, I'll try it, thank you!